# UWP Xaml control for two column text + editor with custom editor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Which control use for organize for CustomObject editor.

Same is PropertyGrid from WinForms

```cs
public Goods 
{
    public string Caption { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Reference ReferenceShort { get; set; }
    public Reference ReferenceLong { get; set; }
}

public Reference
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Must have:

1. Two columns
2. First column is text - property name
3. Second column is editor

a) text (Caption)

c) radiobutton (Enabled)

b) text editor (Name)

c) date picker (Date)

d) combobox (ReferenceShort)

e) text editor + button (ReferenceLong)

4. View mode (when editor column is text) and edit mode (when editor column is specific editor)
5. Allow customize any item

Answer (score 2):

You have a PropertyGrid sample control here:
https://xamltips.wordpress.com/2016/02/12/displaying-details-property-grid-in-xaml/